# In sass can I have &x&y&z

Tags: css, sass

In sass I want to do

```
asdf{
   &-b&-c {font-size: 16px;}
}
```

For the css generated to be

```
asdf.asdf-b.asdf-c{
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

Is this possible to do in sass?
Or am I going to have to write out to parent element multiple times

Comment: If you want to test sass code like that and don't know if it works, you can go to https://www.sassmeister.com/ (or any other sass convert of your choice) and trial and error until you're finished.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I've tried it there, but I couldn't work it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mixins:

```
@mixin fontSize($selector) {
  .#{$selector}.#{$selector}-b.#{$selector}-c {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@include fontSize("asdf");
```

Result

```
.asdf.asdf-b.asdf-c {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were using Less the syntax would be:

```css
.asdf {
  &&-b&c {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

However, Sass doesn't allow for `&` to be directly joined with another `&` in the same selector. Instead, reuse must make use of interpolation (`#{...}`):

```css
.test {
  &#{&}-b#{&}-c {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```